# Joining data points when plotting live data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code that gets real time data from some temperature sensors. The code plots the values obtained from the sensor every 5 seconds or so and plots a data point on the graph. Everything there works fine, so I thought it would probably look better if the points were joined up. I assumed that it would just be a case of adding `linestyle = '-'` on the end of my `plt.plot`, however this does not produce a line joining the points.

I tried simplifying the code to see if I had missed something which I've shown below, but this still doesn't join up the points.

So my question... Is there a way to join up points when plotting live data?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [2,5,2,7,9,4,2,7,6]

i= 0

plt.ion()
plt.ylim(0,10)

for i in range (0,9):
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i], marker = 'o', linestyle = '-')
    i+=1
    plt.pause(1)

plt.show(block=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few conceptual problems with your `for` loop but that is irrelevant for the issue at hand. The problem is, in your current situation, each of your `plt.plot` calls creates a new plot with exactly that data point. What you want to do is create a single plot and update its data.

To fix your example, I'd do it like this

```
plt.ion()
plt.xlim(0,10)  #  Need to make sure both x and y axes have proper ranges
plt.ylim(0,10)
line_plot=plt.plot([],[],marker='o',linestyle='-')[0] # Create an empty plot with which we can work

for xval,yval in zip(x,y):
    line_plot.get_xdata().append(xval) #  Attach a new data point
    line_plot.get_ydata().append(yval)   
    plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: That works for my example that I gave in the question so thanks for the answer. But if I did not know the number and they weren't in a list, so `x = np.random.random()` and `y = np.random.random()*10` that approach wouldn't work. Any way to modify it?

Comment: I have changed the solution so that it only appends to the data inside the line plot. You now only need to get `xval` and `yval` in whatever way you want. Of course, you will need to find a way to deal with the plot bounds.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what `xval` and `yval` are?

Comment: They are `x[i]` and `y[i]` in your old iteration. Note that in Python, `for` will iterate through any list (or any iterable in fact) and you can think of `zip` as constructing a list of pairs `[(x[0],y[0]),(x[1],y[1]),...]`. I have used this to show that you can use any other way to create them as well and do not depend on knowing their index number.